# Can I set the default text to be displayed in every newly created script file in VisulStudio 2010?

Tags: c#, settings

That's it. My question is aboe in the title. I'll try to describe the issue in more detailed way.
When I a new script-file in my DB project it is created with the following text by the default:

```
-- =============================================
-- Script Template
-- =============================================
```

I would like to have another text when creating a new script-file. How can I do this? Is there any settings in VS 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different (at least 2) approaches, that I'm aware of, to achieve what you want.

1. Use templates
2. Use macros

The implmentation of both of them you can find here:

[Add document header for files automatically in Visual Studio](http://abhijitjana.net/2010/12/05/add-document-header-for-files-automatically-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, learning these examples I found the template file in the following path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Extensions\SqlServer\Items
There are templates for scripts in VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact location but there must be a Template File you can modify. Try to search for the title in your VS2010 installation and in the AppData folder of VS2010. You should be able to find the Template.

Comment: You was right! I found the file with the help of articles provided by Tigran. But you were on the right way, thanks!